# Objects: Value always undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am working on some keybinding functionality and came across something that is quite confusing to me.

I am doing some regex validation against the user defined keybinding pattern and would then like to assign the pattern as key and value to definedKeys:

```js
const definedPattern = ['a', 'b']
let definedKeys = {}

const bindKeys = () => {
  const charKey = (String(definedPattern[0]) + String(definedPattern[1])).match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/)
    
  if (charKey) {
    definedKeys[charKey.input[0]] = definedKeys[charKey.input[1]]
  }
  
  console.log(definedKeys)
}

bindKeys()
```

Comment: please add the call of the function and the wanted result.

Comment: Where are you using `definedKeys` though? I see you define it on the first line, but you don't seem to be doing anything with it.

Comment: yes, please create a [mre]

Comment: @rid I'm just logging it for now. I'll make a codepen, brb.

Comment: please use this site for adding the code.

Comment: Even if we fix the obvious mistakes (assigning to `definedCharKeys` instead of `definedKeys`, not calling the function before logging it), you're still expecting the return value of `.match()` to have an `.input` property, which it hasn't; it's an array. This array contains the match, then the partial matches, but your RegEx doesn't define any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `definedKeys` instead of `definedCharKeys` as it is not declared neither initailized
- Assigning value directly to key instead of refrencing value from `definedKeys` because value is not still set and it will be always **undefined**.

```
  definedKeys = {};
  const encodeKey = (pKey) => {
      charKey = (String(pKey[0]) + String(pKey[1])).match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/);
      if (charKey) {
          // charKey.input = 'ab'
          definedKeys[charKey.input[0]] = charKey.input[1];
      }
  }

  encodeKey('ab');
  console.log(definedKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you don't put anything in definedKeys but instead you put it in definedCharKeys?

Answer (score 0):

As per the code. You are not assigning anything in "definedKeys". You are assigning a value in "definedCharKeys" that's why you are getting undefined for the "definedKeys".

Please post full code where are you calling the function so that developers can provide you solution.